# Python social auth steam avatar

Tags: python, django

I'm using python-social-auth in my project. Account successfully created. And how can i get steam user avatar and save it in database?

I am trying to use pipeline like this

```
def get_avatar(backend, strategy, details, response,
    user=None, *args, **kwargs):
  url = None
  if backend.name == 'steam':
    url = response['avatarfull']
  if url:
    user.avatar = url
    user.save()
```

Error - 'SuccessResponse' object has no attribute 'avatarfull'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/steam.py#L32), this information is stored in a `player` key inside the `details` dict.

I'm not sure where the arguments to your `get_avatar` function are coming from, but assuming it is the user details supplied by python-social-auth, then you can access the avatar like so:

```
def get_avatar(backend, strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'steam':
        url = details['player']['avatarfull']
        if url:
            user.avatar = url
            user.save()
```

You probably also need to make sure that the following method is part of [`SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE`](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html?highlight=SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE):

```
'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
```

Comment: Exception Type: KeyError, Exception Value: 'player'  . 

details = {} (empty)

Comment: @АртёмДемко why don't you print the contents of both `response`and `details` to see what is in them. It will be in there somewhere.

Comment: response 
<openid.consumer.consumer.SuccessResponse id='http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/***********' signed=[u'openid.signed', u'openid.op_endpoint', u'openid.claimed_id', u'openid.identity', u'openid.return_to', u'openid.response_nonce', u'openid.assoc_handle']>

Comment: backend <social.backends.steam.SteamOpenId object at 0x7f06f00dbf90>

Comment: I've edited the answer with the likely issue - that you might be missing a step from your pipeline. If that doesn't work then I don't know what the problem is.